# Radius of Convergence for log of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm studying a particular product formula F(z) such that when you take the log of the function you get

$$\log(F(z))=\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{c_n}{n}z^n$$
where $c_n$ is some constant that depends on $n$.

In general, one doesn't know what the $c_n$s are (they are computable, but not given by some sequence). If one were able to compute some radius of convergence $r$ such that $\log(F(z))$ converges for $|z| \leq r$, would that translate to a radius of convergence for $F(z)$, i.e. would $F(z)$ converge for all $|z| \leq e^r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $e^{z}$ is an entire function, i.e. its power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}$ has radius of convergence equal to $\infty$. Given the power series representation of $\log(F(z)) = \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{c_{n}}{n}z^{n}$, we know that $F(z) = e^{\log(F(z))}$ also has a power series representation obtained via composition. Moreover, for any $z$ such that the series for $\log(F(z))$ converges, we immediately have that the series $F(z)$ converges for such $z$. One could show this perhaps a bit tediously by expanding out the terms of the composition series.

Thus knowing that $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} \frac{c_{n}}{n}z^{n}$ for $|z| \leq r$ implies that the power series for $F(z) = e^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{c_{n}}{n}z^{n}}$ centered at $z = 0$ also converges for $|z| \leq r$. Note that the radius would not be $e^{r}$.